# c++: how to optimize IO?

Tags: c++, optimization, io

I am working on a mathematical problem that has the advantage of being able to "pre-compute" about half of the problem, save this information to file, and then reuse it many times to compute various 'instances' of my problem.  The difficulty is that uploading all of this information in order to solve the actual problem is a major bottleneck.

More specifically: 
I can pre-compute a huge amount of information - tons of probabilities (`long double`), a ton of `std::map<int,int>`, and much more - and save all this stuff to disk (several Gb).

The second half of my program accepts an input argument *D*.  For each *D*, I need to perform a great many computations that involve a combination of the pre-computed data (from file), and some other data that are specific to *D* (so that the problem is different for each *D*).

Sometimes I will need to pick out certain pieces of pre-computed information from the files.  Other times, I will need to upload every piece of data from a (large) file.

Are there any strategies for making the IO faster?

I already have the program parallelized (MPI, via `boost::mpi`) for other reasons, but regardless, accessing files on the disk is making my compute time unbearable.

Any strategies or optimizations?

Currently I am doing everything with `cstdio`,  i.e. no `iostream`.  Will that make a big difference?

Comment: Do you have memory available to load some of your data into a cache?

Comment: I would seriously consider buying a SSD, given that the time spent to implement a custom solution (akin to a database system) will be easily worth the $300 you'll spend for the disk. Also I guess that aggressive operating system IO schedulers may help.

Comment: The SSD is a good idea.  Or (assuming this is on a 64-bit machine which would make sense) purchasing 32 GB of memory is a relatively cheap option as well.

Comment: Do you have a parallel file system to support parallel I/O ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. Well, if I am running stuff on a supercomputer somewhere, then SSD is out of the question...

Comment: @CycoMatto: Then most of the few Gb of data should fit somewhere in memory.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'm not sure how parallel i/o would help.  Each processor is accessing different information in the files.  I suppose what you are suggesting is to use "helper" processors, that do nothing but help stream in from a file?  But then they would have to send information to the processor that is going to computew with it - so I'll still get slowed due to extensive processor communication.  Are you suggesting that the speed penalty due to extensvie ocmmunication is better than the io penalty?

Comment: @CycoMatto: if different processes access different files, then they contend for the disk attention (imagining a merchant serving several customers, each in its turn). Parallel I/O systems are a way to get multiple merchants.

Comment: @CycoMatto: if you have a parallel i/o system then multiple MPI processes can read (different parts of) a file simultaneously.  You could, for example, have each process read only the part of the input file it requires, eliminating the need for a process to read data for another process and then pass it across.

Comment: Just curious - how have you measured the performance of the program to be sure that disk I/O is the biggest issue?  If you're looping a lot, or allocating small chunks of memory at a time, it very well could be cache thrashing or fragmentation as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stuff that isn't in a map is easy.  You put everything in one contiguous chunk of memory that you know (like a big array, or a struct/class with no pointers), and then use `write()` to write it out.  Later use `read()` to read it in, in a single operation.  If the size might vary, then use one operation to read a single `int` with the size, allocate the memory, and then use a single `read()` to pull it in.

The map part is a bit harder, since you can't do it all in one operation.  Here you need to come up with a convention for serializing it.  To make the i/o as fast as possible, your best bet is to convert it from the map to an in-memory form that is all in one place and you can convert back to the map easily and quickly.  If, for example your keys are ints, and your values are of constant size then you could make an array of keys, and an array of values, copy your keys into the one array and values into the other, and then `write()` the two arrays, possibly writing out their size as well.  Again, you read things in with only two or three calls to `read()`.

Note that nothing ever got translated to ASCII, and there are a minimum number of system calls.  The file will not be human readable, but it will be compact, and fast to read in.  Three things make i/o slow: 1) system calls, if you use small reads/writes; 2) translation to/from ASCII (printf, scanf); 3) disk speed.  Hard to do much about 3) (other than an SSD). You can do the read in a background thread, but you might need to block waiting for the data to be in.

Comment: I learned programming on my own, so a lot of what you said are new concepts for me.  --> 2) What do you do to avoid translations to ASCII?  I know of nothing other than `fprintf`, `fscanf`, etc.  What are the (efficient) alternatives?

Comment: @CycoMatto, use `fwrite` and `fread` to allow writing/reading binary data directly.

Comment: @DerekPark  Thank you.  I'm gonna be a pain in the neck here.  While I certainly will take advantage of the faster binary format with `fwrite, fread``, I must admit that I also desire to keep some portion of the data human readable.  The precompute is fairly tricky and nuanced, and so I want to be able to check that everything looks reasonable (and for debugging later, I will need to know exact values...).   Should I just keep a separate ASCII version for debugging purposes?

Comment: That's always a challenge.  Human readable is really nice for debugging purposes; pure binary is substantially faster to read.  If you do both, the challenge becomes ensuring they really are the same, and always stay in sync.  Start by having the same method responsible for both.

Comment: @CycoMatto, there is some speed to be gained by using `read()` and `write()` rather than `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  The difference being that the latter do buffer handling for you, while the former can save you one buffer copy.  But you need to learn the interfaces - `open()` takes different arguments than `fopen()` and returns an integer that you then pass to `write()` and `read`, rather than a `FILE *`.

Comment: @CycoMatto, I would pick either human-readable or binary and stick with it.  Mixing the two will give you a file that doesn't really display properly in a text editor and doesn't have the speed benefits of binary.  I go with human-readable as the default for my work and only go to binary if there's a compelling reason.  If you need both, then I would write them as completely separate files so you can easily config the text version off.

Comment: @DRVic, unbuffered isn't automatically faster.  In fact it's generally slower unless you're doing your own buffering.

Comment: @DerekPark, he's looking for the fastest way.  In the answer, I indicated doing a single read() call to get the data into its final location.  If you do read() of single bytes, that is close to the worst of all possible worlds.  But the fastest is to read() into the final destination, saving one buffer copy.

Comment: @DRVic, it's not the typical case that all the data is one gigantic array that can be written/read that way.  And when it is, an `mmap` would probably be a better option.

Comment: @DerekPark, `mmap` might really be the way to go.  It isn't clear from the question which is the more common case - need access to some or all: both cases are mentioned.  An advantage with mmap is that if you only need some, only those parts get faulted in.  A disadvantage is that you lose some control of what gets read in when.

Answer (score 14):

Certainly the fastest (but the fragilest) solution would be to `mmap` the data to a fixed address.  Slap it all in one big `struct`, and instantiate the `std:::map` with an allocator which will allocate in a block attached to the end of the struct.  It's not simple, but it will be fast; one call to `mmap`, and the data is in your (virtual) memory.  And because you're forcing the address in `mmap`, you can even store the pointers, etc.

As mentioned above, in addition to requiring a fair amount of work, it's fragile.  Recompile your application, and the targeted address might not be available, or the layout might be different, or whatever.  But since it's really just an optimization, this might not be an issue; anytime a compatibility issue arises, just drop the old file and start over.  It will make the first run after a change which breaks compatibility extremely slow, but if you don't break compatibility too often...

Comment: To avoid pointer issues, choosing a POD datastructure can help. For precomputed stuff, dynamicity is not required, so a sorted array works.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point.  (The one time I did this, we did restrict everything to PODs, with `char[]` instead of `std::string`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Some guidelines:

- multiple calls to read() are more expensive than single call
- binary files are faster than text files
- single file is faster than multiple files for large values of "multiple"
- use memory-mapped files if you can
- use 64 bit OS to let OS manage the memory for you

Ideally, I'd try to put all long doubles into memory-mapped file, and all maps into binary files.

Divide and conquer: if 64 bits is not an option, try to break your data into large chunks in a way that all chunks are never used together, and the entire chunk is needed when it's needed. This way you could load the chunks when they needed and discard them when they are not.

Answer (score 3):

These suggestions of uploading the whole data to the RAM are good when two conditions are met:

1. Sum of all I/O times during is much more than cost of loading all data to RAM
2. Relatively large portion of all data is being accessed during application run

(they are usually met when some application is running for a long time processing different data)

However for other cases other options might be considered.
E.g. it is essential to understand if access pattern is truly random. If no, look into reordering data to ensure that items that are accessible together are close to each other. This will ensure that OS caching is performing at its best, and also will reduce HDD seek times (not a case for SSD of course).

If accesses are truly random, and application is not running as long as needed to ammortize one-time data loading cost I would look into architecture, e.g. by extracting this data manager into separate module that will keep this data preloaded.

For Windows it might be system service, for other OSes other options are available.

Answer (score 2):

Cache, cache, cache. If it's only several GB it should be feasible to cache most if not all of your data in something like memcached. This is an especially good solution if you're using MPI across multiple machines rather than just multiple processors on the same machine.

If it's all running on the same machine, consider a shared memory cache if you have the memory available.

Also, make sure your file writes are being done on a separate thread. No need to block an entire process waiting for a file to write.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I have no idea what cache-ing or `memcached` is.  Can you recommend some kind of introductory tutorial or explanation (I found the `memcached` library page, but they are assuming some prior knowledge of what cache-ing is).

Answer (score 1):

As was said, cache as much as you can in memory.

If you're finding that the amount you need to cache is larger than your memory will allow, try  swapping out the caches between memory and disk how it is often done when virtual memory pages need to be swapped to disk. It is essentially the same problem.

One common method is the [Least Recently Used Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) for determining which page will be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much memory is available and what the access pattern is.

---

The simplest solution is to use memory mapped files. This generally requires that the file has been layed out as if the objects were in memory, so you will need to only use POD data with no pointers (but you can use relative indexes).

You need to study your access pattern to see if you can group together the values that are often used together. This will help the OS in better caching those values (ie, keeping them in memory for you, rather than always going to the disk to read them).

---

Another option will be to split the file into several chunks, preferably in a logical way. It might be necessary to create an index file that map a range of values to the file that contain them.

Then, you can only access the set of files required.

---

Finally, for complex data structures (where memory mapped files fail) or for sparse reading (when you only ever extract only a small piece of information from a given file), it might be interesting to read about LRU caches.

The idea will be to use *serialization* and *compression*. You write several files, among which an index, and compress all of them (zip). Then, at launch time, you start by loading the index and save it in memory.

Whenever you need to access a value, you first try your cache, if it is not it, you access the file that contains it, decompress it in memory, dump its content in your cache. *Note: if the cache is too small, you have to be picky about what you dump in... or reduce the size of the files.*

The frequently accessed values will stay in cache, avoiding unnecessary round-trip, and because the file is zipped there will be less IO.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your data in a way that caching can be effective.  For instance, when you are reading "certain pieces," if those are all contiguous it won't have to seek around the disk to gather all of them.

Reading and writing in batches, instead of record by record will help if you are sharing disk access with another process.

Answer (score 0):

> More specifically: I can pre-compute a huge amount of information - tons of probabilities (long double), a ton of std::map, and much more - and save all this stuff to disk (several Gb).

As far as I understood the `std::map` are pre-calculated also and there are no insert/remove operations. Only search. How about an idea to replace the maps to something like [std::hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) or [sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/?redir=1). In theory it can give performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

> More specifically: I can pre-compute a huge amount of information - tons of probabilities (long double), a ton of std::map, and much more - and save all this stuff to disk (several Gb).

Don't reinvent the wheel. I'd suggest using a key-value data store, such as berkeley db: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/C/concepts.html

This will enable saving and sharing the files, caching the parts you actually use a lot and keeping other parts on disk.